# meteor[1.3.1] - import node package with builtin module

Tags: meteor, npm

I try to import node-rsa npm package to my project: "import NodeRSA from 'node-rsa';" but i get following error: Cannot find module 'crypto'.

crypto is a node builtin module, so its not installed over npm. Does that mean i can't use 'node-rsa' directly?

https://atmospherejs.com/planifica/node-rsa works without any problems.

planifica:node-rsa - "Browserified Node.js RSA library carefully packed for Meteor"

thanks

Comment: "meteor npm install --save meteor-node-stubs" solved this issue